longitudinal causal mediation analysis with recall periods
I am new to causal mediation analysis (using longitudinal data), and trying to learn best practices.
I have tried to read some methods reviews -- e.g.
Preacher2015,
O'Laughlin2018,
Assaad2022
-- but one gap I can't seem to fill is:
how to consider event-type variables reported within recall periods -- i.e. censored.
Most methods seem to treat variables $X_t$, mediators $M_t$, and outcomes $Y_t$ as truly occurring at time $t$, rather than within $(t-1,t]$, which could undermine the ordering for Granger causality. Has this issue been considered (e.g. with a continuous time model)? If so, I would much appreciate guidance on where to continue reading. Or, am I overthinking it? TIA.
